# How to correctly write +: R × R → R?

Tags: math-operators

When viewing addition on (say) a ring *R* as a map *R* × *R* → *R*, one often writes something like

```
{+}\colon R\times R\to R.
```

However, I assume that perhaps

```
\mathord+\colon R\times R\to R
```

is more correct? Or should I do something totally different (perhaps use a different `\mathX` command)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Independently of whether you use `amsmath` or not, the first atom that follows `+` (ordinarily a **Bin** atom, binary operation), is a **Punct** atom (punctuation).

According to the TeXbook, table on page 170, this is an impossible combination, which means that `+` is considered in this case as an **Ord** atom. So the spacing will be the same as the one used for `f\colon`, that is, no added space. The same table is on page 205 of TeX by Topic, reproduced below with the relative notes.

[image]

With `amsmath` there will still be a space of 2mu (but the same would be with a letter).

In case of doubt, just enclose the **Bin** atom in braces, which will make it into an **Ord** one. Adding `\mathord` in front of it is the same.

Comment: So, anything you put in brackets becomes ordinary? Is that a general rule?

Comment: @Gaussler Yes. Whatever the contents is, it will be treated as a single ordinary math atom.