# Norm of "a" looks different from Norm of "b" in math mode

Tags: math-mode, tilde

I run into the following little problem in the LaTeX math mode:

```
$ \left \|\tilde{a}  \right \| + \left \| \tilde{b} \right \| $
```

when trying this in the [Latex Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), it looks a bit weird: the norm around b is much bigger than the norm around a. Without the `\tilde` over b it acts normal. Is there a way to solve this easily or do i have to change letters? Or is there a smaller way to write `\tilde{b}` ?

Comment: Do you prefer $ \left \|\tilde{a}  \right \| + \left \| \vcenter{\hbox{$\tilde{b}$}} \right \| $ ?

Comment: A smaller way to write `\left \| \tilde{b} \right \|` is `\left \| \smash{\tilde{b}} \right \|`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102157/15925

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `\left\|...\right\|` which are extensible characters (meaning they grow vertically with the content height), use fixed height versions.  You can call on larger versions with `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
$ \big \|\tilde{a}  \big \| + \big \| \tilde{b} \big \| $
\quad
$ \Big \|\tilde{a}  \Big \| + \Big \| \tilde{b} \Big \| $
\quad
$ \bigg \|\tilde{a}  \bigg \| + \bigg \| \tilde{b} \bigg \| $
\quad
$ \Bigg \|\tilde{a}  \Bigg \| + \Bigg \| \tilde{b} \Bigg \| $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Often, you will see the syntax employed of `\bigl\| ... \bigr\|` where the extra "l" and "r" indicate "left" and "right".  While I originally was unsure if they actually affected the typesetting (or if they were purely a mnemonic to help the programmer keep track of matched delimiter sets), Gustavo and Mico (hat tip) assured me that their inclusion *can* affect the typesetting itself.  Mico was kind enough to provide an example, which I recreate here.  I commend his comment below to your attention:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
$ \big \|+\tilde{a}  \big \|  $
\quad versus \quad
$ \bigl \|+\tilde{a}  \bigr \| $
\quad
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\bigl` versus `\big` _does_ affect the typesetting!  But best of all it is to use _mathtools_, as @Mico shows.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: One case where using `\bigl<something>` instead of just `\big<something` makes a big difference is when the subsequent material starts with a unary `-` or `+` symbol: If you use `\bigl`, the "fence" is given TeX type "mathopen" and the unary symbols will be typeset correctly. In contrast, if you use just `\big`, TeX will treat the `-` and `+` symbols as binary rather than as unary operators, with incorrect spacing, etc.

Comment: @Mico I was trying to imagine such a case, and I thank you for bringing one to my direct attention.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for not having dwelt on explanations: I typed my comment at four in the morning, while I was suffering from insomnia.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti No apologies are necessary.  I read your comment late at night and was too tired to explore further at that point.

Comment: +1 for picking up on my comment about `\bigl` vs "just" `\big` making a big difference if the first symbol after the "fence symbol" needs to be typeset as a unary operator. For an earlier posting on this subject see, e.g., [Why use the control sequences \bigl, \biggl, \bigr or \biggr, as I can always use \big or \bigg?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19480/5001) For a more in-depth discussion of how TeX determines the math-mode spacing around various symbols, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240579/5001) by (who else?!) @egreg.

Comment: Just came across an even earlier posting on using `\bigl` or "just" `\big`: [Difference between \big and \bigl](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1232/5001) if the first symbol after the fence symbol is an arithmetic operator. My apologies for not mentioning it in the previous comment.

Answer (score 13):

Typographically speaking, it's neither necessary nor advisable to auto-size the norm bars placed around various variable names. Using the default size of the double-vertical bars for `a`, `b`, and `\tilde{b}` should be fine.

Instead of using the low-level directives `\lVert` and `\rVert` directly in a formula, it's preferable to declare a high-level macro named, say, `\norm` in the preamble and to use it in formulas. That way, the code immediately becomes more readable (and easier to debug, if necessary).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
$\norm{\tilde{a}} + \norm{\tilde{b}}$  \quad default size

\medskip
$\norm[\big]{\tilde{a}} + \norm[\big]{\tilde{b}}$ \quad\verb+\big+ size

\medskip
$ \left \|\tilde{a}  \right \| + \left \| \tilde{b} \right \| $ \quad \verb+\left ... \right+ method: much too large!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Plus, “`\left … \right` constructions are treated as ‘inner’ subformulas, which means that they will be surrounded by additional space in certain circumstances” (_The TeXbook_, bottom of p. 155).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti not when you use the `\norm*`, `mathtools` will _fix_ that additional space. Internally `\norm[\big]` is also converted into the `\bigl` and `\bigr` versions.

Comment: @daleif: Yes, I know: I made my remark because Mico’s code mentions a `\left … \right` construction, probably with the intention of comparing the right way of doing things with the wrong one.  Indeed, I said in another comment that _mathtools_ and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command is _the_ solution to this type of problems.

Answer (score 7):

For a simple code, we can use `mathtools` and `etoolbox`, to define a `\norm` command, which has a `star` version (automatically adapted to the size of its argument) and a `nostar` version which accepts an optional argument: `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg`, if you want to fine-tune the size of the vertical rules. The `DeclarePairedDelimiterX`, w.r.t. `DeclarePairedDelimiter` has an argument which allows to insert a macro between the delimiters – here, it inserts a dot if `\norm` has an empty argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, etoolbox}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
   & \norm{\tilde{a}} + \norm{\tilde{b}} &\qquad & \norm*{\tilde{a}} + \norm*{\tilde{b}} &\qquad & \norm[\big]{\tilde{a}} + \norm[\big]{\tilde{b}}\\
 & \norm*{\frac{\tilde{b}}{\tilde{a}}} & \qquad & \norm[\bigg]{\frac{\tilde{b}}{\tilde{a}}}& \qquad & \norm{}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see `\norm{}` in your code, yet I see in the picture  the output that (if I understand well) it is supposed to produce.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I hadn't included it first, then thought it would demonstrate a little more, added the result, but forgot to update the code! Corrected now.

Comment: You may want to mention which benefits (if any) `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` enjoys over `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. This might help, at the margin, inform readers as to which variant of the macro they should choose for their own documents.

Comment: @Mico: You're right. You were posting your answer while I finished to write mine, and was tempted to delete it, as they're very close. Finally I decided to leave it due to this difference,, but the least I could do was to explain it. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed-size large delimiters as in the other answers are one option, but another way to ensure delimiters have the same size in such situations is to use `\phantom` and friends:

```
$ \left\| \vphantom{\tilde b} \tilde a \right\| + \left\| \tilde b \right\| $
```

Comment: Given that the double-vertical bars are too tall anyway, typographically speaking, when they surround just `\tilde{b}`, why would you want more of the too-tall bars?

Comment: In this specific case, shorter bars may look better. However, this solution is applicable generally to situations where delimiters with uneven sizes break some sort of a symmetry in a formula, and in most cases it’s desirable to keep the larger size for both.